# Adding a # to my WordPress menu item is not working correctly

Tags: wordpress

I added a # to a custom link in my WordPress menu because I don't want it to go to a page.

When I click on the link it adds a # at the end of the URL.

Then I am not able to click any other links in the menu when the # is in the URL.

Does anyone know why I can't click a link or a better solution to adding a # as the link of a menu item?

Thanks!

Comment: Sharing a link would be good idea.

Comment: The site is under development so I can't share a URL, is it possible to figure this out without the link?

Comment: Can you share some screenshots; back-end & front-end?

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a guess here but you could add this to functions.php to disable the default action of a specific menu item. Just change the menu ID once it is created and plug it in.

```
$("#menu-item-num").on("click", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```